# How to subscribe multiple observable in rxjs 6 ? do is not a function in rxjs 6

Tags: react-native, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

In `rxjs 5.5.12`, I created a `login()` to `subscribe` with multiple observable by `do()`

```
login(userEmail, userPassword).subscribe((response) => {
  console.log(response);

  if (response === 'something') {
    // some actions
  } else {
    // some actions
  }
},(error) => {
  // some error actions
});
```

I use rxLoginPOST to call api:

```
rxLoginPOST(url, params) {
  return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(somePromise).catch(handleErrFunction);
}
```

I use it in login function it return multiple observable:

```
login(email, password) {
  return APIService.shared.rxLoginPOST('users/signin', { ...arguments })
  .flatMap((response) => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
        return Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
          myObservable1,
          myObservable2,
          myObservable3
        )
      } else {
        return Rx.Observable.of(response)
      }
  }).do((result) => {
      if (result.length > 0) {
        // some logic
      } else {
        return Rx.Observable.of(result)
      }
  }).flatMap((result) => {
      if (result.length > 0) {
        return this.checkUserIsRegistered()
      } else {
        return Rx.Observable.of(result)
      }
  })
}
```

In `rxjs 6.5.3`, I had changed all the import like

```
import { Observable, combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, map, catchError, flatMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

If I trigger `login()` it will show `do is not a function`

So I change the code:

```
login(userEmail, password) {
    return APIService.shared.rxLoginPOST('users/signin', { ...arguments }).pipe(
        mergeMap((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          return combineLatest(
            myObservable1,
            myObservable2,
            myObservable3
          )
        } else {
          return of(response)
        }
      }).tap((result) => { // I am stuck here, I have no idea how to continue with it...
         console.log('check 4');  // check 4 does not appear.
         console.log('response', response);
         return of(response)
      }
    );
```

I try to use `tap` instead of `do`, but check 4 does not appear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pipe`, you should chain your operators like this: `pipe(op1, op2)` and not like `pipe(op1).op2()`

```
login(userEmail, password) {
    return APIService.shared.rxLoginPOST('users/signin', { ...arguments })
      .pipe(
          mergeMap((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
              return combineLatest(
                myObservable1,
                myObservable2,
                myObservable3
              )
            }
            return of(response)
          }),
          tap((result) => { 
            console.log('check 4');  // check 4 does not appear.
            console.log('response', response);
          })
        );
```

I also removed your useless `else` statement since you are returning something before :)

**EDIT**: As suggested in comments, the `return` instruction from `tap` has also been removed since unecessary

Comment: Note: `tap` does not need to return anything